# How to solve "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the code that I am providing below to convert csv to tfrecord in pycharm, but I can't get the tfrecord file. I get this message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a 
NewWriteableFile:  : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
```

I searched different option but none provide me a solution, maybe I don't understand something or there is a mistake in the code that I have not found

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
import io
import sys
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import protos
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
from numpy import split

csv_input = "C:/Users/Documents/Model 
A/MTrain_labels.csv"
output_path = "C:/Users/Documents/Model A/"
image_dir = "C:/Users/Documents/Model A/Base"

flagsMJ.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flagsMJ.DEFINE_string('output_path', '','Path to output TFRecord')
flagsMJ.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')

def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == "MM":
        return 1
    elif row_label == "JJ":
         return 2
    else:
         row_label = None

def slipt(df, group):
     data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
     gb = df.groupby(group)
     return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), 
     gb.groups)]

def create_tf_example(group, path):
     with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as 
     fid:
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

      filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
      image_format = b'jpg'
      xmins = []
      xmaxs = []
      ymins = []
      ymaxs = []
      classes_text = []
      classes = []

      for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
          xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
          xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
          ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
          ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
          classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
          classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

     tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
         'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
         'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
         'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
         'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
         'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
         'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
         'image/object/bbox/xmin': 
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
         'image/object/bbox/xmax': 
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
         'image/object/bbox/ymin': 
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
         'image/object/bbox/ymax': 
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
         'image/object/class/text': 
          dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
          'image/object/class/label': 
          dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
          }))
          return tf_example

 def main(_):
    writer = 
    tf.compat.v1.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: 
    {}'.format(output_path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```